# COUNTROWS and FILTER for multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a simple Order table that contains some basic information for each order:

```
Order   Order Date  Value
105268  01.01.2020  500
```

Then I have a transactional table, that contains for each order the routing steps:

```
Order Step Status  Date
105268  A1  P   01.01.2020
105268  A2  T   08.05.2020
105268  B1  S   10.05.2020
```

Now I need a measure, that counts all orders, that contains a Status "S" but not "P" or "T".
But how? I think I need a COUNTX to aggregate these information in the end into the corresponding granularity level, right`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each order is unique in the `Order` table, you can simply filter based on your conditions and count how many rows are left.

```
Status_S_not_P_or_T = 
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        'Order',
        VAR Statuses =
            CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Transactions[Status] ) )
        RETURN
            "S" IN Statuses &&
            ISEMPTY ( INTERSECT ( { "P", "T" }, Statuses ) )
    )
)
```

Comment: Wow, many thanks! It works perfectly fine. Why did you choose CALCULATETABLE for this purpose?

Comment: The CALCULATETABLE is there to perform a [context transition](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/) so that the list of `Status` values computed corresponds to the `Order` row context.